# Fetch JSON array using WebClient and Json.Net and display it in textview?

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2015, json.net, xamarin.android, webclient

My Activity code is:

```
private void MClient_DownloadDataCompleted(object sender, DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    string json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Result);
    var Details = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
}
```

My doctor.cs class code is:

```
namespace App12
{
    public class Doctor
    {
        public string DoctorId { get; set; }
        public string doctorName { get; set; } 
        public string specialityId { get; set; }
        public string experiance { get; set; }
        public string fee { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public Doctor doctor { get; set; }
    }
}
```

JSON array is:

```
{
  "0": {
    "DoctorId": "1",
    "doctorName": "DR.Rama",
    "specialityId": "1",
    "experiance": "5 years",
    "fee": "300rs"
  }
}
```

I am trying to show this in `textview` but it gives me an error:

> System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems here.

1. Your class structure doesn't quite match up with the shape of the JSON data.  This JSON isn't technically an array either; it's a dictionary.  You need to deserialize into a `Dictionary<string, Doctor>`.
2. When calling `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` you need to specify a type parameter.  If you don't, the return type will be `JObject`.  This may be the cause of the `InvalidCastException`.

Try it like this:

```
var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Doctor>>(json);
```

From there you can loop through the doctors like this:

```
foreach (var doctor in dict.Values)
{
    textView.Append(doctor.doctorName);
}
```